# Where are the repositories for Blender add-ons and scripts?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I want to create a 3D representation of data where the representation is a plot of a set of values as displacement differences along one axis, relative to the other two axes. Since I've never had what I though was a really good idea that someone else hasn't had first, I'm sure that a script must exist that would take a table of data as input, and map it to the vertices of grid object. But I have been unsuccessful in finding the right combination of search terms either to find such a script, or to find a listing of Blender scripts where such a script might be located (somewhat like the GIMP repository). Does such a repository exist, and I'm just too inept to find it? And even if the repository does not yet exist (and I think it would be a really good idea to have one), does such a script exist?

Comment: See http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts

Comment: [This blog](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com.au/) lists a lot of addons, the rss feed helps keep you up to date as new ones are found. [This blenderartists category](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?48-Released-Scripts-and-Themes) is another source.